# Giving full control permission to one user on only one page

Tags: permissions

So i would like to give full controll permission to a user to only one page and keep his default permissions to  any other page on the current site.

If i use "Share" button on the page, and add the user to full controll group will he get full control only on the page i just shared and stay with his default permissions on other pages?

thank you

Of course i'm asking this because i don't want to break inheritence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to give different permissions then what is set on the entire site without breaking the inheritance.

That's exactly what you are looking to do is break inheritance.

If you use the **Share** button it will automatically break inheritance for you if you do it from the list view of the Site Pages or Pages library (wherever your page exists).  If you click the **Share** button on the top of the site it will share the entire site, not just the page you are on.

Breaking inheritance isn't a bad thing.  I wouldn't recommend doing it everywhere, but it is a very valuable solution if used appropriately.